# Mac Web Sharing Subdomains

Tags: macos, subdomain

I'm using my mac's web sharing for my websute, and was wondeering if it is possible to add a subdomain to the mac web sharing...

Thanks

-Techy

Answer (score 0):

You can. But i am not sure whether any UI is available for that.
What you need to do is to edit the apache2/httpd.conf file and add virtual hosts to it.

Comment: so would that work even if i port forward the mac web sharing(im not using mac server)